# Struggling with the design for a simple logic circuit

Tags: led, circuit-design, timing, binary, multivibrator

I'm working on a circuit that would store 4 bits and flash them on an LED. These would be stored on a 4 bit register, and should be outputted when a button is pressed. My goals is to take my 4 outputs from the register, and flash each of them on a single LED for an exact amount of time (something like 100ms). I can't figure out a way to turn these 4 outputs into one digital signal for my LED. This also needs to be precisely timed. I was thinking about using an astable multivibrator with 4 outputs controlling the 4 outputs of the register with transistors, but I would run into the problem of it looping more than once per button press. Any help would be useful.

Comment: What do you mean by "precisely timed"?  And tell us more about the looping?

Comment: It needs to be precise. For example, every LED pulse would last exactly 100ms before the next one.

Comment: what should display for a `0000`? ... what about a `1111`

Comment: There's no way to get "exactly" 100 ms. RC oscillators/555s will get you to maybe within a few percent even trimmed with a potentiometer, and with very poor temperature stability, a more sophisticated chip could get you to within 1%, crystals can get you to ppm range, and CSAC to ppb.

Comment: It doesn't have to be "exactly" 100ms. I'm using this to do close range infrared transmition, and it needs to be pretty precise for that so the receiving end works. For 0000 it would stay off, and for 1111 it would stay on for the duration of the transmition, then go back to idle/off until pressed again.

Comment: Use a MCU? Reprogrammable = you can experiment with timing etc as much as you want, and it can drive the LED.

Comment: This is for a school project and the goal is to make it as simple as possible, so with as little programable chips as possible.

Comment: Shift register and 555?

Comment: How would that work? (I'm pretty new to this)

Comment: If you're working on a circuit can you share what you have already?  If you cannot use a small micro-controller chip there are parallel in/serial out shift register chips. Look at the datasheet of a 74HC165 for example: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc165.pdf

Comment: If the LED stays off for 0000, how does the receiver know that it has been sent? Similarly, how does the receiver distinguish between 0001, 0010, 0100 and 1000, which all look like a single flash? Hint: do you understand how a UART works, and why it has a "start" bit?